# Conclut de ? et qu'est-ce qui est remplacé par les ici ?

Tags: sens, pronoms

[image]

J'ai plusieurs questions sur les deux phrases. Dans la première, pourquoi y a-t-il deux « de » ? De quoi le sociologue conclut-il ?
Dans la deuxième, qu'est-ce qui est remplacé par le pronom « les » ?

Comment: Two different questions — please post a thread for each in future

Answer (score 4):

1. L'expression est *conclure de A à B* ([II A 1](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conclure)). Elle signifie : Étant donné A, on conclut que B. Ici donc, voyant l'impossibilité de discerner entre deux choses, le sociologue a conclu qu'il n'y avait aucune distinction réelle entre ces choses.
2. *Les* désigne les deux types de suicide : il ne faut que repérer le groupe nominal le plus récent qui est au pluriel. (On conclut de là que ces deux types sont également les deux choses entre lesquelles ce sociologue ne voit pas de distinction.)

Answer (score 1):

**I**

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conclure)) **A.** − Emploi trans. indir. Conclure (de qqc.) à
> **1.** **Conclure de qqc. à qqc**
> ♦ Après un minutieux examen, Ortègue avait conclu à une paralysie par compression.  (P. Bourget, Le Sens de la mort,1915, p. 97)
> ♦ Conclure de ces ambivalences à une absence totale de conscience personnelle (Mounier, Traité du caractère,1946, p. 539)
> ♦
> Quant à M. de Piagnes, il ne se sentait attiré que par les jeunes filles qui ne disaient pas un mot dans les bals; il concluait de là à leur honnêteté; ... Montherlant, Les Célibataires,1934, p. 751.

- « conclure **de** l'impossibilité de discerner **à** l'indistinction réelle »

Seulement le premier « de » appartient à cette construction du verbe « conclure » ; le second fait partie du groupe nominal « impossibilité de discerner » ; ce groupe nominal de noyau « impossibilité » définit une impossibilité particulière, c'est celle de discerner. Cela veut dire qu'il n'est pas possible de voir des différences. Dans la construction c'est le premier qqc. Dans la phrase donnée il est donc dit que des conclusions sont faites sur la base d'une impossibilité de discerner ; en d'autres mots une impossibilité de discerner  est apparue dans le processus, et il a été conclu qqc ; ce qqc, le second, c'est qu'il existerait une indistinction réelle, c'est à dire que l'on serait confronté à un cas où aucune différence existe. On peut paraphraser tout cela de manière plus simple mais moins élégante en disant que d'un cas où on ne peut pas voir de différences on déduit que c'est un cas où il n'y a pas de différences.

**II** « Les » ne remplace rien, c'est l'article défini (pluriel), et donc sa fonction est la détermination du nom ; le nom   « caractère » est utilisé pour nommer tous les caractères d'une cetaine sorte, ceux-ci étant *ceux qui sont communs à toute mort volontaire* ; donc c'est un groupe de caractères  bien déterminé, et l'article défini pluriel est le seul qui convienne. Si on utilisait « des », cela voudrait dire que le groupe de caractères communs à toute mort volontaire, n'est pas complet, qu'il est formé selon un choix dans le groupe complet et donc qu'il n'est pas bien déterminé (on peut former de nombreux groupes). C'est pour cela que l'article « des » est appelé « *article indéfini* »